Manipular valores en una grafica con Plotly
Miren, mi problema es que estoy intentando procesar unos datos, que al graficarse a traves de una regresion lineal, me toma 4 puntos de pendiete maxima de 4 curvas diferentes, la cuestion es que toma esos puntos sin mucha discriminacion. Entonces quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de mover esos puntos en el grafico que se genera, para obtener valores mas coherentes.
Este es el codigo:
# Crea un gráfico interactivo con Plotly
fig = go.Figure()

# Agrega tus puntos de datos como trazos de dispersión
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=domo_res.data['TT'], y=domo_res.data['Y'], mode='markers', name='Mediciones'))

# Agrega los puntos de pendiente como trazos de dispersión editables
for rank in range(1, 5):
    X = domo_res.data.loc[domo_res.data['rank']==rank,'TT']
    Y = domo_res.data.loc[domo_res.data['rank']==rank,'Y']
    EA = domo_res.data.loc[domo_res.data['rank']==rank,'EA'].head().iloc[0]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=X, y=Y, mode='markers', name=f'{rank}: {EA:.3f} mm/hr', marker=dict(symbol='circle', size=10), showlegend=True, visible='legendonly'))

# Establece el diseño del gráfico
fig.update_layout(
    title='Gráfico de Evaporación',
    xaxis=dict(title='Fecha y hora (HH:MM)'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Gramos de agua por metro cúbico de aire'),
    height=600,
    width=1000,
    hovermode='closest',
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type='buttons',
            buttons=[
                dict(label='Modo Edición', method='relayout', args=[{'dragmode': 'select'}])])])

# Muestra el gráfico interactivo
fig.show()

